# Match for custom comment block required

Tags: javascript, regex

Bascom uses a special format to comment out blocks of code. I want a RegEx that matches this block to be used in SyntaxHighlighter.

These comment blocks starts with '( and ends with ').
Yep, it's so stupid.

Example input:

```
    bla
    '(
    test
    test
    ')
    blubb
```

I tried:
    '\(.*?\)'
and many others without success.

Expected return after replace:

```
    bla
    #####
    blubb
```

where ##### is the replacement.

Basically just like C++ & similar /* .. */ rule. But I can't get it working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const data = `    bla
    '(
    test
    test
    ')
    blubb`

const result = data.replace(/'\([\s\S]*?'\)/g, "#######");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted. Sadly, my reputation is too low for upvoting. It works perfectly, many thanks!